# Why is my layout broken only in Firefox and IE8 (not 9)?

Tags: html, css, layout, cross-browser

I noticed today that a website that I've completed months ago was not showing well on Firefox and IE8 (works fine in IE9). It's quite old now and I'm pretty sure that I tested browser compatibility at the time but I guess one does make mistakes.

Problem is I can't seem to understand the problem. Basically I have a left floated sidebar with a fixed position but it renders on the right (outside its container) on FF and IE8. I could always build the layout again from scratch (it uses Skeleton Grid system) but would still like to understand the problem.

[Example page that's broken on the website.](http://tsolomunkh.com/about/)

Try to open it with various browsers and see for yourself. Also, if someone views it right on FF, I'm interested too.

Thanks a lot!

Edit: I'm not asking for a whole debugging. Just if someone knows of this issue.

Edit2: Validator links are irrelevant here. I checked it already and they're basically prefixes for css and CMS-related for html.

Edit3: I fixed it and prepared a kinda complete answer to post but as I'm a new user, I can't answer my own question in the next 7 hours... so here it is:

> I just sorted the whole thing out with hints from your answers (thank
>   you!).
>
> Basically, it's something to do with how browsers handle floats on
>   fixed elements. Imagine we're dealing with successive "float:left"
>   element, which is the case in most grid system (960gs, bootstrap,
>   etc.).
>
> Here's how browser will handle these elements without fixed
>   positioning: http://jsfiddle.net/cPjdK/ And with float:right :
>   http://jsfiddle.net/cPjdK/1/
>
> Now what if we have a very long third column and want to fix the first
>   (my example)? Well it basically disables the floats because fixed
>   elements are out of the flow. http://jsfiddle.net/cPjdK/9/
>
> So you have to position them absolutely (or with margins in my case)
>   http://jsfiddle.net/cPjdK/6/
>
> Now what about my website? The fixed elements were floated anymore and
>   the whole grid system kinda fell apart. Fixing this appeared to be a
>   long work. But, for some reason, replacing my "float:left" properties
>   on floated elements with "float:right" basically fixed it. Why did it
>   fix it? Why was it not working on FF and IE8 but appeared fine on IE9
>   and Chrome.
>
> I have no idea.
>
> But it looks fine now (after a few tweaks) and I've already been paid
>   so...
>
> Problem solved but question unanswered, sorry...

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftsolomunkh.com%2Fabout%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 fix those first - you have a duplicate class=""

Comment: I don't think anyone will debug your entire site for you - try to recreate the problem as simply as possible - ideally in something like jsFiddle

Comment: There arent only prefixes - you are using class attribute twice on same tag which can screw up things. Check the validation list better.

Comment: The double class is due to wordpress (CMS) adding classes on its own. It's a pain, I know...

Answer (score 1):

You have a FIXED positioned element without giving it any coordinates.

Try giving it something like:

```
#side-right{
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
}
```

Comment: The problem is I need to keep my floated positioning. Grid system pain... Anyway, I just kinda sorted the whole thing out, I'll post the answer for curiosity.